# Secure DNS vs. Private DNS - is there a difference?

Tags: private-dns

I want to use a custom DNS that works perfectly well on my Android phone (Pixel 6 Pro) using "Private DNS" however, does not work on my Google made Chromebook (Pixelbook, so also technically part of the Pixel family) that utilizes "Secure DNS." Everything I can find suggests that the differences between the two privacy-enhancing DNS offerings exists in name only, but my experience with this in particular is telling me otherwise. It may be relevant to mention that I'm not using the traditional ip/hostname but rather the alternative host name, as that's all that Blokada provides. At least for Blokada Cloud use, anyway. However, come to think of it, I think I use an alternative hostname for Quad9 and that's working on the Pixelbook, so who knows? Anyway, I'm hopeful somebody more knowledgeable than I on the subject might be able to share some insight as to why I'm having so much difficulty getting something that works with Private DNS working using Secure DNS

Ps I confirmed my suspicion. On the Pixelbook, "https://dns.quad9.net/dns-query" works in place of 9.9.9.9/149.112.112.112 however "Google--Google--Pixelbook-**********.cloud.blokada.org" fails, everytime... Without fail. Also, I'm not sure I'd even have the option to use it otherwise, but I have enabled the necessary flags to use Secure DNS

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note while Pixelbook shares the "Pixel" series naming, it's a Chromebook and thus runs on Chrome OS, which is a totally different OS from Android. As such, while this community might explain the difference between those features, setting up Chrome OS is out of scope if it's not about interacting with Android devices or Android apps. You might be interested in our sister sites [su] for general computing hardware (including Chromebook) or [unix.se] for Unix-based OS (including Chrome OS).

Comment: Thanks for not outright deleting my comment. Not at all arguing with your statements, as everything you stated is true however just as ChromeOS has a Linux compatibility layer/environment, while it's not called an "Android compatibility layer," it really feels like it's getting the same treatment. Especially when you look at the FS/file tree. Just as Linux has, Android has a dedicated section (called Play Files or something) that mirrors Android's FS to the letter. Both are very much separated from the main "MyFiles" section belonging to ChromesOS "proper"

Comment: I just reread your comment. I should have specified sooner that my question came about entirely as a result of interaction with an Android app, Blokada 6, downloaded from the Google Play Store where I'd previously subscribed to the paid service Blokada Cloud. It is this app that provided the alternate DNS address referenced in my original post that I'm trying to get working with ChromeOS' Secure DNS. The process is exactly the same on an Android phone but where using Private DNS results in success, following the same steps fails with Secure DNS.